# Multi Select Drop down, overlay with CTA buttons

Tags: forms, buttons, dropdown, cta, overlay

Have a multi-select dropdown - which on expand is overlaying the CTA buttons on the form. I have to click elsewhere for the dropdown to close, (since it a multi-select dropdown the general behavior of close panel when an option is selected will not apply) and then click on CTA. I can't change the position of CTA also. Recommendations, please

image attached.[image]

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot of your complete page ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the CTA buttons not moved, best way to imagine as an alternative solution is to reverse the arrow on the right-corner of the dropdowns in my point of view.

[image]

While you may have them pointing out downwards as usual when they're closed, you may have ***the arrows pointing upwards*** when the multi select dropdown's options revealed as above. By allowing user to click that arrow, ***it lets the dropdown collapse*** so that, your users freely complete the desired action within your forms via CTA buttons.

> You should also think about applying animations during these
> transitioning (opening/collapsing) cycles.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following feedback for you:

1. You can drop it up instead of down if you have fewer options and enough space above your inputs.
2. You should not use a checkbox inside the select option like that instead, you can show the currently selected options by the user with an 'x' button on them.
   [image]
3. Since I don't know the whole case and user interface that you have made I would recommend that if you can make sure that on clicking in the background ( when select is not in focus ), the menu is getting closed.

Thank you,
Let me know if you think this answer could be made better.

Answer (score 0):

Sidenote: In addition to the response of @user88702,

Checkboxes are necessary at a point when you search for something and want to select multiple things in one go! This should be checked against the user behavior pattern in your product